# c# confirmation messagebox during drag and drop freezes file explorer

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window with a `DataGrid` storing objects of `Document`.  When I drag and drop a file from file explorer, I add it into the `DataGrid`.  However, if the `DataGrid` already contains an object with the same name, a `MessageBox` is displayed asking if the user would like to replace the existing `Document`.

The problem is that when the `MessageBox` is displayed, it freezes file explorer. I can't close, minimize, etc. If file explorer is displayed in front of the `MessageBox`, I have to pick it from the taskbar. I'm lost as to why it is freezing file explorer, and how to fix it. Any help would be awesome!

The code:

```
private void MainWindow_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    gridDragDropVisual.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void MainWindow_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    gridDragDropVisual.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void MainWindow_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    gridDragDropVisual.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    // Get dropped data
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        foreach (string obj in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            // If data is a directory
            if (Directory.Exists(obj))
            {
                // Get files in directory
                string[] detectedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(obj, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                // Add files to list
                files.AddRange(detectedFiles);
            }
            else // If data is files
            {
                // Add files to list
                files.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        // Add files as documents
        AddItems(files.ToArray());

        // Populate datagrid
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = documentList = Documents.Get();
    }
}

private void AddItems(string[] items)
{
    foreach (string file in items)
    {
        string fileName = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);

        // Create new document
        Document newDocument = new Document(file);

        // Get any existing document with the same name
        Document existingDocument = documentList.FirstOrDefault(objDocument => objDocument.fldName == fileName);

        if (existingDocument != null)
        {
            switch (MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, string.Format("There is already a document that exists with the name '{0}'.\n\nWould you like to replace it?",fileName), "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question))
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                {
                    // Remove existing document
                    Document.Remove(existingDocument.pkDocumentID);

                    // Add document to database
                    newDocument.Add();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Add document to database
            newDocument.Add();
        }
    }
    // Populate datagrid
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = documentList = Documents.Get();
}
```

Comment: That is entirely by design.  The D+D notifications are generated by the drag source on its dispatcher thread.  Explorer's in this case.  Your MessageBox.Show() call is blocking, so Explorer cannot resume its dispatcher.  It will look frozen, it cannot respond to input anymore.  You could use your own Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method to get your code to run after the event handling completed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it runs in the same thread and therefore pauses everything else. The solution would be letting the `MessageBox` run inside another task:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Represents a wrapper for using task based messageboxes.
/// </summary>
public static class AdvancedMessageBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does show a messagebox inside another task, so it has rather no impact to the main thread.
    /// </summary>
    public static void TaskBasedShow(
        string message,
        string caption,
        MessageBoxButton buttons,
        MessageBoxImage image)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            OnRes?.Invoke(MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, image));
        });
    }

    public delegate void OnResult(MessageBoxResult res);

    /// <summary>
    /// Will get triggered, when the user pressed a button on a messagebox (after calling TaskBasedShow).
    /// </summary>
    public static event OnResult OnRes;
}
```

Implementation:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AdvancedMessageBox.OnRes += MessageBox_OnRes;
    AdvancedMessageBox.TaskBasedShow(
        "My message",
        "My caption",
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
        MessageBoxImage.Question);
}

/// <summary>
///     Is getting triggered after the user pressed a button.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="res">The pressed button.</param>
private void MessageBox_OnRes(MessageBoxResult res)
{
    // Implement you logic here
}
```